# stuck in process sock.connect(sa) or making connections

Tags: python-3.x, linux, kali-linux

I just set up Kali with GNOME3.38 desktop, and also have set up the python development tools I usually use. But when I start to use `imapclient` in the interactive python shell and do: `conn = IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)` or:

```
with requests.get('https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE') as response:
       print(response)
```

nothing really happens rather than just be stuck. I hit `Ctrl + C` to stop the process and I see the **same tracebacks.**

```
>>> import requests
>>> with requests.get('https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE') as response:
...     response.raise_for_status()
... 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and for the imapclient:

```
>>> conn = IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 284, in __init__
    self._imap = self._create_IMAP4()
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 321, in _create_IMAP4
    return tls.IMAP4_TLS(
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imapclient/tls.py", line 44, in __init__
    imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imapclient/tls.py", line 49, in open
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Now, I didn't really mess with anything else in my kali machine.. But is it GNOME that's causing this, or is there something wrong with the files in kali?

Another problem is that `pip install [library_name]` takes too long to process. My internet speed is okay for the speed, btw.

Answer (score 16):

I had that problem too where even a simple `pip list` took ages and were stuck the following error.

This can basically happen if your host has IPv6 support but your network doesn't.
You can quickly check so by disabling IPv6 support on the fly with:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Once you disabled IPv6, try pip again.
You might also check if a simple ping resolves to an IPv4 or IPv6.

Also, in my case, noticed that my OPNsense firewall did block a lot of stuff with suricata.
Some rule tweaking later I got stuff to work.

Hope this helps ;)

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 247, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 141, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 387, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 662, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 662, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 244, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Got the same issue while virtualizing Ubuntu 22 LTS via Parallels in a MacBook Pro M1. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Helped for me as well. Thank you.